# MySQL database is loading very slow

Tags: mysql, wordpress, joomla

I have a wordpress installation which has over 5000 posts in it. For the last few days, the database is loading very slowly. I have used the database optimization plugin as well as optimized db tables from back end. But still the issue exist. After I restart the MySQL server everything seems to work just fine. The same issue exists for my other website which is a Joomla installation on another server(Amazon) and has over 50,000 articles. Even here I regularly do database optimization but still the pages load very slowly. Sometimes to over 1 minute. There is page cache on both the sites, still I am getting this issue. There are other websites also running on the same server but they are relatively new and less content compared to these two sites, they load very fast. The problem is with these two websites only.

Comment: Do you have any persistent processes? `SHOW PROCESSLIST` can indicate what queries might be stalled. Have you tuned your MySQL server by adding memory to the appropriate engines?

Comment: Yes I have added memory to the myisam and innodb buffer size. SHOW PROCESSLIST does not show anything. But when I use SHOW STATUS, innodb data read, key read requests, key reads, opened files, queries, table locks immediate, uptime, uptime since flush status is very huge. Especially for queries, key read requests and table locks immediate.

Answer (score 2):

Check out:

- Connection pool. Maybe you're running out of connections and get bottlenecked
- Server's cache
- slow queries audit

... this are just hints, to get real help you should indicate more system performance's info

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the Wordpress site configuration settings, but for Joomla, if you are not already running MySQLi, I would recommend enabling in in the Global Configuration. Try clearing the site cache and if you are running on Joomla 1.5, then if possible, upgrade to Joomla 2.5 as it is a little faster when running queries. In the end, it might just be due to the fact that you are on a shared host, so if you are willing to, a VPS server would speed things up.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reason for the same like : "Hosting Server Issue (use dedicated server for such sites)" , "Use good cache plugin availabe for joomla & wordpress" , "Use db optimize plugins"

You can also refer to following sites -
http://www.sparringmind.com/speed-up-wordpress/
http://wpmu.org/too-many-wordpress-plugins/
http://www.joomlaperformance.com/articles/performance/so_you_want_to_speed_up_joomla_3_14.html